# "Fastest way to unzip many files on iOS" or "How else can I download many files quickly into my iOS app"

Tags: ios, iphone, zip, mapkit

In my app i want the user to be able to download offline map content.

So I (compressed) moved all my tiles into a zip file. (I used 0 compression)
The structure is like that: {z/x/y.jpg}

```
+0
+-0
+--0.jpg
+1
+-1
+--0.jpg
+2
+-2
+--1.jpg
```

So basically there are going to be many many files for zoom level 0-15. (about 120.000 tiles for my test-region).

I am using https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive now but also tried out https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive before and both are pretty slow. It takes about 5!! minutes on my iPhone 5S for the files to unzip.

Is there any way I can speed things up? What other possibilities rather than downloading the tiles in one big zip file would there be?

Edit:
**How can i download the content of the whole folder quickly to my iPhone without the need of unzipping something?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering how I was ending up:
For my use-case (MapTiles) I am using MBTiles now instead of zipped images. It's one big database file and super easy to read if using FMDB. No unpacking whatsoever needed...

Even if I was placing the Images all in one binary file without any compression, the "extracting" still took forever!

Answer (score 1):

JPGs rarely compress at all with zip - they are by definition already compressed. What you should do is create your own binary file format, and put whatever metadata you need into it along with the images (which you should encode with a really low quality number, to get their size down).

When you download those files, you can open then, quickly read them into memory, and extract out data or images as needed.

This will be really fast and have virtually no overhead if your extra data is binary (not text).

PS: I just tripped on a [PHP Plist class](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList)

Comment: I wasn't trying to use zip to compress the files, but just to have them in one file so that i only need one file download. I even tried the to zip it without compression... isn't speeding up things...

Do you have any other idea on how i can download the content of a folder to my iPhone quickly?

Comment: I just told you. Define your own binary format to pack the data into one or more files. Think of a C structure, where you have an image as the last value in the struct, and the field just before it is its length. You read in the structure up to the image, you now know the length, you read in the image, now your file pointer is pointing at the next struct. If you have a really big file, you can decode each "structure" in the background as it arrives - no need to wait for the whole file. In fact you don't really need to have a file on either side, as you can stream data down.

Comment: Isn't there an easier solution? The main problem I see with this approach is that I would have to write a little tool that creates those binary files. That makes it harder to maintain them for clients... Isn't there a format out there that makes kind of the same and is open source with existing tools to create it and to unpack it?

Comment: DMG files for example?!? I just haven't found anything on the web on how to mount/extract them on iOS... :(

Comment: There is python code around that can create binary plists. So if you provide it with an array of dictionaries, where the image is a data blob in the dictionary, it will compress to a small size and be about as open source as you can get. You can open it then directly in iOS. Not sure about streaming (real time decoding). You cannot put binary data in a json dictionary, so if you want a known format, go with binary plist.

Comment: If you google "binary plist" you'll get a slew of links. Also, a binary plist file on the device can be opened many different ways - you can open it with NSArray's arrayWithContentsOfFile. There is a doc on plists:  "Property List Programming Guide" that clarifies much. Also poking around now, it looks like you can get C# and Java code to also create them. If you look you can probably find code that fits into your server model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46582/discussion-between-georg-and-david-h)

Comment: I just did a little test on this... I am writing all the files into one custom defined binary. On the Mac that's super fast. But extracting it on the iPhone is super slow again... It's the [NSData writeToFile:atomically:] that's taking forever! Any idea on how to speed that up?